Is there a way to run JS file using node.js via cmd without using full path to the file
I am trying to run test.js via cmd which is not located in the current directory.
When I run:
"node test.js" I get "Error: Cannot find module" error.
When I run:
"node C:\temp\test\test.js" all works as intended.
Generally speaking, is there a list of directories node will look through to find a file? Or it only searches folder it is run from?
I tried adding my directory to "PATH" environmental variable, but it did not work.
I cannot find a flag for node that could be interpreted as a "start script in this directory".
I realize the potential danger, but this is more of the exploration for further development.
There is no server involved, no browsers, I am doing JS stuff on one machine using cmd to process some JSON files.
Thank you in advance!
I tried adding my directory to "PATH" environmental variable, but it did not work.
I tried moving the file to any of the "PATH" folder, but that did not work.
I tried reading help to try to locate "Start in X directory" flag.
